# Anylogic: Restrictions for functions

Tags: java, anylogic

I am modelling a production system with the material-handling blocks. Each production machine has a queue and a machine. Each order has an individual processing time on the machine.

Currently I have function for each machine, but I would like to simplify the model and put all of the calculations into one function. But that means that the function is called very often by different agents throughout the production system.

I am a bit worried, that this could lead to problems (e.g. the wrong agent is assinged the processing time or anylogic could choke on this.
Could this happen or am I simply too careful?

Comment: Also, please use SOF for very specific tech questions, not these general "should I do X".  See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community

Comment: Thank  you, then I will keep it separate. As it also touches the area of "how does anylogic work" I considered it to be not general but rather tech-related. But I will try to adapt to stack overflows customs.

Comment: Yeah, even "how does AL work" is too general for SOF, ask those on LinkedIn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AnyLogic model is run in a single thread so even if "...the function is called very often by different agents throughout the production system" the function will only ever be called by a single entity at any given time.

Unless your function is static this will also not be an issue if you use Monte Carlo or Parameter variation experiments where different threads each run an instance of your model.

So you are safe.